# Firebase React. How can I access my Auth values in React / Webpack?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack, firebase-authentication

I'm not sure how to write this question so please let me know if you need any more information.

I'm building an online shop web application. I'm coding the login functionality using Google's Firebase authorisation API.

It logs in fine and inside the: **user.getToken().then** function, I can console.log the **displayName** just fine. If it was a static webpage, i could append it to the DOM too.

Inside react/webpack though, I want to set the **displayName** string as my **usernameState** state. It doesn't work, when I run this.setState inside the **user.getToken().then** function, it fires an error, see below.

I would like to be able to use that value on the webpage/react states.

```js
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      usernameState: ""
    };

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        var displayName = user.displayName;
        var email = user.email;
        var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
        var photoURL = user.photoURL;
        var uid = user.uid;
        var providerData = user.providerData;

        user.getToken().then(function(accessToken) {

          console.log(displayName);

          this.setState({
            usernameState:JSON.stringify(displayName) //cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
          });
        });
      } else {
        // User is signed out.
        console.log("signed out");
      }
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });



  };
```

Comment: For anyone coming accross this problem, I simply put const self=this below: this.state = {usernameState:""}; 
Thanks to @Jiang YD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a bind or save real `this`

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      usernameState: ""
    };
    const self=this;
    ...
    self.setState(...)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Incredible, it worked. Thank you so much. Could I trouble you to explain why this worked and how would one make a bind?

Comment: `this` is one of the key points in JS, plz have some learn, if you want to use JS in long time.